# Why is User Agent Stylesheet overriding my CSS stylesheets in Safari 7.0.0

Tags: html, css, safari, user-agent

we have a landing page that looks and works great in all browsers except for Safari 7.0.0.  We have added a div with id="counter" that is set to "display: flex;" and that style is being applied correctly in every browser except Safari 7.0.0 (on Mac). Somehow in Safari 7.0.0, that CSS style is being overridden by the User Agent Stylesheet for "div" which is applying "display:block;".  We have tried everything we can think of to fix this problem, such as making sure we are using the correct doctype, adding "!important" to the CSS styles in question and even adding inline styles, but to no avail!! This problem is only happening on my Employer's computer, any assistance anyone can give us would be much appreciated!

```
#HTML
<div id="counter" class="center-block text-center counter-wrapper">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="time">
              <span id="days"></span>
            </div>
            <p>Days</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="time">
              <span id="hours"></span>
            </div>
            <p>Hours</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="time">
              <span id="minutes"></span>
            </div>
            <p>
              <span class="hidden-xxs-down">Minutes</span>
              <span class="hidden-xxs-up">Min</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="time">
              <span id="seconds"></span>
            </div>
            <p>
              <span class="hidden-xxs-down">Seconds</span>
              <span class="hidden-xxs-up">Secs</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="time">
              <span id="milliseconds"></span>
            </div>
            <p>
              <span class="hidden-xxs-down">Millisec</span>
              <span class="hidden-xxs-up">Msec</span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- End Counter -->


#CSS
div#counter .counter-wrapper{
 display: flex !important;
 justify-content: space-between;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 85%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 -webkit-display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the older version of Safari 7.0.0, any CSS rules utilizing Flex need to be preceded with "-webkit-", please see the documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp
Also, it would probably just be best for the person with the problem computer to finally update their version of Safari to the latest one. Safari 7.0.0 came out in 2013....!